# GeoServer, select feature, highlight it, and export it to PNG

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, cql-filter

Like any GIS Web application, you need to provide a facility to print a report with a part of map, and specially the position of a given ParcelID on the map with different zooms...

I have GeoServer, simply, I want a script that accepts a filter (something like `ParcelID='ABC123'` and returns me a PNG URL of this Parcel highlighted on the map with all the other parcels and layers...

I know the `WFS` with `GetFeature` and `Filter` return some row data about this parcel, and I know the `WMS` can return a map with `CQL_FILTER` but only for the needed parcel without any other parcels, so it's not enough for me.

Would you please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask for two layers in your WMS request - one with all the parcels drawn (use your usual or a default style) and a second with the filter and a different style specified. The url will look like normal but for

> layers=parcels,parcels&styles=,red&cql_filter=;ParcelID=1

Note the ; at the beginning of the filter to show there is no filter for the first parcel layer.

Comment: Seems interesting .. and what about having the bbox for the parcel extent and -1 zoom ?

Comment: I think you'd need to do a WFS request to get the bounding box of the parcel (and then add a bit) before you asked for the image

Comment: Yea , i did that , i got an array of coordinates , this is the missing point now , how can i get the BBox based on this array of coordinates ?

Comment: that array is the bbox - just extract minx,miny,maxx,maxy and concatonate

Comment: Is it the BBOx for the first zoom ? If so How can i calculate for other zooms ?

Comment: I got the point , i extracted the pairs minx,miny,maxx,maxy and played with values (+5 -5 etc) to get a bigger bbox(es) coverage , you made my day .. Thanks a lot